# Adding nonce ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2, nonce

Ruby nonce throwing error

```
require 'date'
nonce = DateTime.now.to_i
```

Error:

```
undefined method `to_i' for #<DateTime:0x000000015336e8> (NoMethodError)
```

Working in my console it gives correct value

```
2.1.0 :014 > nonce = DateTime.now.to_i
 => 1405065242
```

**Why it throws error programatically?**

**EDIT**

**Is there any way to add nonce. The condition is it should be a integer that has to be incremented on every subsequent request**

Comment: where is it not working?

Comment: If you are using `irb`,then it probably throws error.

Answer (score 0):

As Pavan sais, if you run your code in `irb` it probably will not working anymore.

According to the [doc](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.2/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-c-now), Ruby hasn't method to_i in DateTime class.

However, Rails override DateTime class to have a [to_i](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/DateTime.html#method-i-to_i) method:

So, I think you run the command whick works in an Ruby On Rails environment, that's why it works. But if you run in a Ruby environment without Rails, it will not work.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Is there any way to add nonce. The condition is it should be a integer that has to be incremented on every subsequent request